# How do I stub a "secondary" method with Sinon?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, stub, sinon

I'm creating unit tests for a `Question` model in a Node.js API. At some point someone updated the `Question.create()` method such that it calls a method on an `Expert` model. I need for my tests to ignore this subsequent call the the `Expert` method.

I've tried several variants of something like this:

```
var notifyExpertStub = sinon.stub(Expert, 'notifyNewQuestion', function() {});
```

A `console.log()` print in `Expert.nofityNewQuestion` shows me that the method is still being called. I'm thinking that this is because the `Question` model requires the `Expert` model and is loading a new instance within itself, but that could be way off.

From a test of a method on one model, how can I stub a method on a secondary model? In case I'm using the terminology in an ambiguous manner, my requirement is this: When called by `Question.create()`, `Expert.notifyNewQuestion()` should simply do nothing. Like it doesn't even exist.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: My best guess is that `Question.create` and the `stub` call use different `Expert` references, or `Question` grabs a reference to `Expert.notifyNewQuestion` before you get a chance to stub it.  Where I've run across cases of the latter, I've forced re-initialization of the dependent, so that it uses the stub as a dependency.

Comment: That's exactly it. I ended up stubbing the method into my unit test instance and injecting that object into the model method as an optional parameter. It's not as clean & simple as I'd like, but it's working.